# Regex involving nested delimiters/quotes

Tags: php, regex

I have a string that is enclosed by either apostrophes or double-quotes.  Within the string, the other ('non-enclosing') character may appear.  I'd like to extract the contents of the string using regex.

Example: `string = "isn't";` and I want to extract `isn't`.

Using `/[\'"]([^\'"]*)[\'"]/` doesn't work because it doesn't impose the constraint that the string is opened and closed by the same character.

Using `/([\'"])([^\'"]*)(?1)/` fixes that, but disallows the 'other' character from occurring within the string.  I need something like `/([\'"])(!(?1)*)(?1)/` but how do I write that?

As a bonus, can I avoid capturing the opening character so that `?1` contains the string contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group index 1 contains the characters which are present within the double quotes or single quotes.

```
(?|"([^"]*)"|'([^']*)')
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kJ5oL9/2)

**OR**

You could use the below regex also,

```
([\'"])((?:(?!\1).)++)\1
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kJ5oL9/3)

**Pattern Explanation:**

- `([\'"])` Captures the starting single or double quotes.
- `((?:(?!\1).)+)` Captures one or more characters but not of the character which was present inside the group index 1.
- `\1` Must end with a character captured by the group 1.

Comment: Thanks!  I think I need to change the `\1` at the end to `(?1)` in PHP.  That second one looks most promising, because I've got some extra matching inside the quotes (which isn't relevant to the question), so I'd prefer not to duplicate everything for apostrophe and for double-quote.  I'll test it out.